# changing image of imageview dynamically

Tags: android, imageview

i have a list defined by the layout list_item_new.xml in which i have an imageView and 2 textViews. ImageView is defined like this

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/listimage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"

        android:gravity="center"

        android:src="@drawable/users2"
    />
```

i am using the same ListView on 3 different screens. 
Now what i want is that the image on this imageView should be different for all the 3 screens. i am trying to change to image like this

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService
             (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_new, null);
        listimg=(ImageView)ll.findViewById(R.id.listimage);
        listimg.setImageResource(R.drawable.office);
```

office.png is an image in drawable.

the whole code is executing but the image is not changing. please tell me what should i do to change the image. i am writing this code in onCreate method of activity and after this i am assigning the data to the list

thanks

Comment: Have set it in the getView() method...?

Comment: no i dont know about this. plz explain.

Comment: Are you dealing with the list or you are using the activity...please confirm it...

Comment: please add some more code

Comment: i am using an activity to set the data to the list by using simpleAdapter.

Comment: In you adapter class there is a getView() where you'll inflate the same layout...place this code there...or post the Adapter class code,,I'll show you how do you do that..

Comment: i am not using the adapter class.

Comment: String from[] = { "line1", "line2" };
  
  int to[] = {R.id.line_a,R.id.line_b };
  sa = new SimpleAdapter(mContext, ar1, R.layout.list_item_new,
    from, to);
  lv.setAdapter(sa);

Comment: You need to create a class that extends SimpleAdapter and override the getview method...

Comment: @pragnani i know that but i dont know how to do that. can you plz give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this class

```
public class Adapter extends SimpleAdapter{

public Adapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, String>> data,
        int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, data, resource, from, to);

}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
 View row = convertView;
 if (row == null) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    row ll = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_new, null);
    listimg=(ImageView)ll.findViewById(R.id.listimage);
    listimg.setImageResource(R.drawable.office);

    textView=(TextView)ll.findViewById(R.id.<textViewID>);
    textView.setText("Hello");
 }

 return row;
}

}
```

Comment: i am doing the same this time. image is changed now but i am not getting the data in textviews now. am i require to do the same for textviews also in getView?

Comment: see that I edited the answer, two lines for textview you can repeat for other text view or for any other also.